# Setting up data for MANOVA in SPSS

Tags: spss, manova

I do not understand how to arrange my data in SPSS for running MANOVA.
I have 6 groups of participants that have rated 100 pictures on 3 different dimensions (dim1, dim2, dim3).

What I don't understand is this:

Do I have to use the mean value for the 3 dimensions (dim1, dim2, dim3) (say, mean of 120 participants) and then make every picture a variable (p1, p2......p100)?
Or do I have to again get the overall mean of all the pictures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, every measure would be a variable and in SPSS you should stick to the rule that one row = one participant (i.e. the “wide format”). In your case, that would leave you with 300 variables (100 pictures x 3 dimensions), which is a lot (and in fact too many if you have 120 participants).

Depending on what you want to know, one solution could be to compute means *per participant* (i.e. means of all 100 pictures for each participant/dimension combination) and run a MANOVA on those. The idea is that all pictures are seen as exemplars of the same thing and you are not interested in any differences between them. Multiple trials just help you reduce error and the MANOVA will tell you how the groups differ in the way they rate the pictures as a whole. It would however miss some other patterns of difference (imagine that people in group A all rate picture 1 higher than picture 2 on one dimension and that's it's the other way around in group B; means could be the same even if the groups clearly differ).

Otherwise, you might want to look into multilevel models, which are much more flexible and allow you to properly account for the structure in your data. This situation is very similar to common psycholinguistics experiments and you might find useful guidance in this literature, e.g.

Baayen, R.H., Davidson, D.J., & Bates, D.M. (2008). Mixed-effects modeling with crossed random effects for subjects and items. *Journal of Memory and Language,* 59 (4), 390-412.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I am running MANOVA on the means per participant/dimension. I shall read the paper you suggested and see whether I should go for multilevel models.